# C# Windows Forms ListView get columns real width after autoresize by width = -1?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, width

I've come through some auto column (`ColumnHeader`) widths on WinForms `ListView` control.

`Width = -1` sets auto-width based on content width and -2 sets based on header and content.
However I cannot find any way to get the auto-computed width which is then set by -1/-2.
Width property of `ColumnHeader` items returns -1.

Is there any way to obtain the real width in pixels which was auto-computed by setting the property to -1/-2?

Thank you!

Comment: Read the `ColumnHeader.Width` property right after assigning the `-1` or `-2` values. It will return the real width.

Comment: Use the `ColumnHeader.AutoResize()` method to set the size mode, the meaning is much more clear. The `Width` property of the ColumnHeader always returns the value set in the native Control (via `SendMessage -> LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH`): it always returns the size in pixels.

Comment: @dr.null It will not return the real width. Adding 20 to width will result in width 19.
See here: https://i.ibb.co/w0jZwF6/stackoverflow.png

Comment: Yes. `20 - 1 = 19`. Double check what you are doing and read carefully the second comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ColumnHeader.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle style)` will do.

Then ColumnHeader.Width property returns the actual width.